# Java initial assignment

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my previous years of development in C++, I know that it was a convention to always initialize your variables with *something*.

I've carried that convention with me to Java, and really any other programming language I use.

I use IntelliJ IDEA, and I am completely happy with it, and usually follow its programming guidelines and warnings, however I got this warning:

```
public String getText(By by) {
    String text = null; // Variable `text` initializer `null` is redundant

    WebElement ele = findElement(by);
    highlightIfDemoMode(ele);

    String tagName = ele.getTagName();
    if (tagName.equals("input")  ||
        tagName.equals("select"))
        // For field elements, the text is actually held in values, not the text.

        text = ele.getAttribute("value");
    else
        text = ele.getText();

    return text;
}
```

Now obviously, in Java,

```
String text;
// is the *exact* same thing as..
String text = null;
```

Considering IntelliJ is very good at following programming conventions, should I neglect that convention of mine to not initialize my variables like this in Java?  I feel it's much cleaner, but if Java conventions tell me not to, i won't.

Could somebody tell me if it's better practice to initialize, or just infer that it's null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One compiler difference is

```
String text;
text.toString();
```

Is a compile error.

```
String text = null;
text.toString();
```

compiles, but is a runtime error.

Compile errors are better than runtime errors. Not declaring your variable until you *have* a value for it is better than either, but sometimes impossible.

```
int x;
try(SQLRunner runner = new SQLRunner(connectionPool) {
    x = runner.getX();
}
```

Is necessary. Consider making your variables *final* in this case, however. This is good practice when possible anyway, but I personally find it too verbose and not helpful to declare every *local* variable that will not change as final. This is an exception because `int x;` tells me it's going to be changing later without telling me how much it's going to change.

```
final int x;
```

Comment: Note though that you can extract the construct into a separate method and avoid this rather ugly pattern.

Comment: @biziclop you can extract anything into a separate method to avoid any pattern (e.g. double-nested for loops with a break break). I think it's reasonable to want to not break this out, especially if you want it visually obvious from the top-level method when connections are checked out.

Comment: I've been told that making a variable `final` allows the compiler / JVM to make some optimisations it couldn't make otherwise, such as inlining?

Comment: @djechlin Of course whether you want to break it into a separate method depends on the actual context. But it's useful to know that in general the `Object foo; try { foo = bar(); } catch(...) {}` construct can be replaced with something that looks better.

Comment: @Stewart Optimizers are getting smarter every day so that isn't much of an advantage. The real advantage of having `final` local variables is that you won't accidentally re-assign them, and you can refer to them in anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @Stewart `final` is good practice when possible. It's a necessity when dealing with highly concurrent code. But it improves readability for class variables for sure. For local variables in function I think it can be overkill (not worth the clutter) but in my opinion in above example I would use it. I can't speak to compiler optimizations but it's certainly plausible.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Effective Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch#Effective_Java) it's bad practice to declare and initialise local variables before their first use. (And according to me too but I'm not much of an authority.)

The idea is to keep their scope as tight as possible, this improves readability and stops accidental re-use.

Comment: that makes sense.  though, i don't know if i have had one instance where I "accidentally re-used" a field.

Comment: @sircapsalot It's usually a result of cut-and-pasting, which is a bad practice in itself.

Answer (score 2):

The following fragment is a Java compile error:

```
    Integer integers[] = {};
    Integer max;
    for (Integer i : integers) {
        if (max == null || i > max) max = i;
    }
```

The error in Eclipse is "The local variable max may not have been initialized".

So you have to initialize max to null.

I wonder what Intellij says...

Comment: That's not Eclipse to my knowledge, that's Java compiler. (it's been long enough since I compiled with javac I may be wrong.)

Comment: Could very well be. Eclipse has its own compiler, too. I wonder what intelliJ does?

Comment: Right, I was trying to think of an example of when it'd be necessary, and this is one of those times.. from the other answers, It seems like the best way is to not initialize.. but these things could creep up, and I like things to be uniform.. if i have to do it here, i'd *like* to do it everywhere else

Comment: i am wondering same. even in intelliJ, it gives compiler error if you don't have any assignment before using variable.

Comment: if anyone wonders TOO much you can slap the above code in class M { public static void main(String[] a) { ... } } and run javac on that.

Comment: To quote the JLS: `If a declarator does not have an initialization expression, then every reference to the variable must be preceded by execution of an assignment to the variable, or a compile-time error occurs by the rules of §16.`

Comment: I guess IntelliJ's attitude must be "All that is permitted is required, and all that is not required is forbidden".

Answer (score 1):

Local method variables are not initialized by default, you're thinking of class fields. Regardless, I would eliminate the local `text` variable completely,

```
public String getText(By by) {
  WebElement ele = findElement(by);
  highlightIfDemoMode(ele);
  String tagName = ele.getTagName();
  if (tagName.equals("input") || tagName.equals("select")) {
    return ele.getAttribute("value");
  }
  return ele.getText();
}
```